# Ejecutar script al hacer click en botón html

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer un html que de a escoger al usuario unos valores, y que a través de un script, estos se sumen y devuelvan el resultado, pero no acabo de entender cómo puedo sumar los valores, ni tampoco cómo retornar el valor al hacer clic sobre el botón que he hecho... A ver si alguien puede aclarármelo un poco, gracias desde ya! Os dejo los códigos (los comentarios son cosas que he ido probando y no he querido borrar por su posible utilidad, así es como tengo los códigos ahora mismo):

```
<script type="application/javascript">

var a = null,b = null,c = null,d = null;

function sumar () {
    var total = 0;  
    //valor = parseInt(valor);

    //total = document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML;

    //total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;

    //total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));

    //document.getElementById('resultat').innerHTML = total;

    total += document.getElementsByName("a").value;
    total += document.getElementsByName("b").value;
    total += document.getElementsByName("c").value;
    total += document.getElementsByName("d").value;
    return total;
}



</script>
```

Ejercicio 5

```
<fieldset>

    <legend>Entra quatre números</legend>
    A: <input type="number" name="a">
    B: <input type="number" name="b">
    C: <input type="number" name="c">
    D: <input type="number" name="d">

</fieldset>

<p>A+B+C+D = </p> <p id ="resultat"></p>


<input type="submit" value="Executa el programa" onclick="sumar()">
```

Comment: Revisa lo que haces con la variable "total" una vez que se ha sumado todo. Sólo la estás devolviendo, pero no la muestras.

Comment: Acabo de probar con un document.write y además de no mostrar nada, me cambia a otra página, tampoco estoy seguro de estar haciendo el tema de la suma bien...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero** que todo, es mucho más rápido obtener un elemento mediante `getElementById()` (ya que deben y tienen que ser valores ***únicos***) ya que si lo haces mediante `getElementsByName()` obtendrás un *arreglo* (ya que el atributo `name` no es único y varios elementos pueden tener el mismo a diferencia del atributo `id`) y tendrás que recorrerlo y procesarlo, etc.

**Segundo:** no estás usando las variables `a`, `b`, `c` y `d` por lo que las eliminé para hacer más legible el código.

**Tercero:** debes parsear el valor tomado de cada `input` con la función `parseInt()`

**Cuarto:** en tu función `sumar()` estabas haciendo un `return total;` pero no estabas poniendo dicho valor donde querías

**Quinto:** solo usa `<button type="submit"></button>` cuando dicho botón esté dentro de un `<form></form>` de lo contrario siempre usa `type="button"`

```js
function sumar() {
  var total = 0;

  // Este será nuestro elemento donde poner el valor total de la suma
  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  
  // Aquí vamos sumando los valores traídos de los input
  // encontrados por su atributo id="" parseados a un número literal
  // con la función parseInt()
  total += parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  total += parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
  total += parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
  total += parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value);
  
  // Aquí le decimos al elemento resultado que nos muestre la suma
  // de A+B+C+D = total
  resultado.innerHTML = 'A+B+C+D = ' + total;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

  <legend>Ingrese cuatro números</legend>
  <!-- Cambiamos nuestro atributo name por id --> 
  A: <input type="number" id="a"><br /> 
  B: <input type="number" id="b"><br /> 
  C: <input type="number" id="c"><br /> 
  D: <input type="number" id="d">

</fieldset>

<p id="resultado">A+B+C+D = </p>

<!-- cambiamos nuestro type="submit" por type="button" -->
<input type="button" value="Sumar" onclick="sumar();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro un ejemplo para la solución a tu problema, comentado.

```js
function sumar(){
//Buscamos en nuestro documento los input que tienen un nombre; a,b,c,d.
 var a = document.querySelector("input[name='a']");
 var b = document.querySelector("input[name='b']");
 var c = document.querySelector("input[name='c']");
 var d = document.querySelector("input[name='d']");
 //Buscamos un elemento por su id; resultat
 var r = document.getElementById("resultat");
 //Agregamos una variable suma y sumamos todos los valores
 //Ojo: En Javascript puedes convertir un valor a entero con tan solo anteponerle el simbolo + (mas), pero no aplica cuanto tienes algo como; a1, esto te daria error, pero si funciona con: 1a (devuelve: 1).
 var suma =((+a.value)+(+b.value)+(+c.value)+(+d.value));
 // agregamos el resultado dentro del span.
 r.innerHTML = suma;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

    <legend>Entra quatre números</legend>
    A: <input type="number" name="a"><br/>
    B: <input type="number" name="b"><br/>
    C: <input type="number" name="c"><br/>
    D: <input type="number" name="d"><br/>

</fieldset>

<p>A+B+C+D = <span id ="resultat"> </span></p>


<input type="submit" value="Executa el programa" onclick="sumar()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando `name` y `getElementsByName` por tanto lo correcto es `total += document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value;` en lugar de `total += document.getElementsByName("a").value;` y para asegurar se interprete como número aplicar conversión antes de su uso 
`total += parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value);`.

Desde luego tambien puede hacer uso de `getElementById` para ello cada input en vez de poner su `name` usa `id`; ejm: `<input type="number" id="a">`

Otra cosa que tienes es que al final de tu función usas solo return y no la asignas a nada; sería:

```
document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML=total;
// Como el tag P tiene "id" el getElementById funciona.
```

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByName('name')](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) Siempre retornará un arreglo dado que puede haber más de un elemento con el mismo atributo nombre.

Para solucionar tu problema bastaría con acceder al primer elemento que retorna la `getElementsByName()`  , además no olvidar de realizar el cast a dicho valor.

```
parseInt(document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value);
```